# I want to get the selected radiobutton using saved prefrences but the activity is not opening?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Here is the code

```
public RadioButton selectedSex;
public int selectedRadioButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_personal_data);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    // 0=FULL_NAME
    // 1 =BIRTHDAY
    //2=ADDRESS_LINE
    // 3=CITY
    //4=STATE
    // 5=PINCODE
    // 6=PHONE
    mUserPersonalInfo[0] = findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    mUserPersonalInfo[1]=findViewById(R.id.user_birth_date);
    mUserPersonalInfo[2]=findViewById(R.id.user_address_line);
    mUserPersonalInfo[3]=findViewById(R.id.user_city);
    mUserPersonalInfo[4]=findViewById(R.id.user_state);
    mUserPersonalInfo[5] = findViewById(R.id.userPhoneNumber);
    mUserPersonalInfo[6] = findViewById(R.id.user_pincode);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mSex=findViewById(R.id.user_sex);
    mNext = findViewById(R.id.personal_details_next_button);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("personalPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    selectedRadioButton  = mSex.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    selectedSex  = findViewById(selectedRadioButton);

    mUserPersonalInfo[1].setText( sharedpreferences.getString("userDOB", null));
    mUserPersonalInfo[0].setText(sharedpreferences.getString("userName", null));
    mUserPersonalInfo[2].setText(sharedpreferences.getString("userAddressline", null));
    mUserPersonalInfo[3].setText(sharedpreferences.getString("userCity", null));
    mUserPersonalInfo[4].setText( sharedpreferences.getString("userState", null));
    mUserPersonalInfo[5].setText( sharedpreferences.getString("userPhone", null));
    mUserPersonalInfo[6].setText(sharedpreferences.getString("userPincode", null));
    selectedSex.setSelected( sharedpreferences.getBoolean("userSex", false));
  //  mNext.setProgress(0);

   // FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //    mNext.setProgress(1);

            final String Birthday = mUserPersonalInfo[1].getText().toString();
            UserName = mUserPersonalInfo[0].getText().toString();
            final String Addressline = mUserPersonalInfo[2].getText().toString();
            final String City = mUserPersonalInfo[3].getText().toString();
            final String State = mUserPersonalInfo[4].getText().toString();
           PhoneNumber = mUserPersonalInfo[5].getText().toString();
            final String Pincode = mUserPersonalInfo[6].getText().toString();


   editor.putString("userName", UserName);
            editor.putString("userPhone", PhoneNumber);
            editor.putString("userDOB", Birthday);
            editor.putBoolean("userSex", selectedSex.isChecked());
            editor.putString("userAddressline", Addressline);
            editor.putString("userCity", City);
            editor.putString("userPincode", Pincode);
            editor.putString("userState", State);

            editor.apply();
```

> Process: com.teepe.teepe, PID: 18864
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.teepe.teepe/com.teepe.teepe.KYC.personalData}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioButton.setSelected(boolean)' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioButton.setSelected(boolean)' on a null object reference
>           at com.teepe.teepe.KYC.personalData.onCreate(personalData.java:92)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `mSex.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` is not returning correct Id.

Because of this `findViewById(selectedRadioButton)` is not able to find the View. and Hence, NullPointerException in the `setSelected` method call.

Comment: yes mSex.getCheckedRadioButtonId()  is returning -1 but why earlier it was working

Comment: @ChiragGupta upvote if the answer helped and also accept if it worked. Let me know if you need help. You can paste the rest of the code to verify why its -1.

Comment: @ChiragGupta check your code where you are setting the id. or paste it here so we can check.

Comment: @ChiragGupta mSex is the RadioGroup and in xml, all RadioButtons are inside this mSex RadioGroup? Correct? Also if no RadioButton is checked as it would be by default. getCheckedRadioButtonId would return -1. So show an error in dialog to user that he/she has not selected any option.

Comment: yes you are correct so i should by default select a radio button thanks I will try it

Answer (score 0):

In this is not find the view

`RadioButton selectedSex   = findViewById(selectedRadioButton);`

must be like :

`RadioButton selectedSex   = findViewById(R.id.selectedRadioButton);`